# Dynamically select specific child div to detach

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parent-child

I have a button that every time you click it I want to be able to detach the div behind the one with a class "selected" inside the div wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="height:122px; width:765px;">
    <div class="smallImage"></div>
    <div class="smallImage"></div>
    <div class="smallImage selected"></div>
    <div class="smallImage"></div>
    <div class="smallImage"></div>
</div>

$('.wrapper').children('.smallImage')[0].detach();
```

I have tried other variations of children() and :nth-child(1) with no prevail.

Basically as long as I can choose the position of the div I want to detach I will be a happy coder, As i will need to detach divs further than 2+ places behind it if that make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Your `div`s are not closed properly (missing `</div>`?)

Comment: Copied it out of chrome as it is made my a php script.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like:

```
$(".wrapper").children('.smallImage.selected').next().detach();
```

...is what you want.  This will call `.detach` on the div immediately following the `.smallImage.selected` div.

If you had a specific number you wanted to select, you could use:

```
.children('.smallImage:not(.selected)').eq(number);
```

Comment: The first one works well but needed to use prev(). Im trying to now get the second one to option to work as it seems to be deleting the last div whatever number I in. Any ideas. Thanks